# Parse week strings for comparison using Java 8

Tags: parsing, datetime, java-8, java-time

I want to compare string representations of weeks, e.g. week "01/17" is before "02/17" and after "52/16".

The following code throws an exception, I guess because my string doesn't hint at the exact day of each week. However, I don't care - it could all be Mondays or Thursdays or whatever:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ww/YY", Locale.GERMANY);
LocalDate date1 = formatter.parse(str1, LocalDate::from);
```

Do I need to modify the parser? Or parse to some other format? Unfortunatley there is no object like YearMonth for weeks...

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a “week” here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to always default to the same day, say the Monday. You could build a custom formatter for that:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .appendPattern("ww/YY")
          .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
          .toFormatter(Locale.GERMANY);
```

You can now build `LocalDate`s representing the Monday of the given week:

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("01/17", fmt);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("52/16", fmt);
System.out.println(d1.isAfter(d2));
```

which prints `true` because 01/17 is after 52/16.

Comment: Great, the parseDefaulting() was the missing piece :)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a way for this to work with the `DateTimeFormatter` class, but I would like to suggest a different approach.

The [Threeten Extra library](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/index.html) contains a number of classes that were deemed too specific to include in the `java.time` library. One of them is the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class you mention.

Your problem can be solved by parsing the week-number and year manually from the input-string and then invoking the `YearWeek` creator-method like this:

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of(year, monthOfYear);
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know this library. What I found very weird is that a formatter build via a pattern string fails to provide the details required to create a YearWeek using from(). However, one constructed via a DateTimeFormatterBuilder works. That is unfortunate, though, since I want to supply the pattern from config.

Comment: @Tom Or alternatively - with many more extras - there is also my lib Time4J which offers the class [CalendarWeek](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarWeek.html) including good i18n-support and week-arithmetic (with methods like `plusWeeks()`). Both are missing in Threeten-Extra. But ONLY for comparing calendar weeks, adding an extra dependency does not seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
YearWeek.parse( "2017-W01" )
```

## ISO 8601

> Or parse to some other format?

**Yes, use another format.**

Use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when serializing date-time values to text. The standard includes [support for week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

For a year-week that would be four year digits, a hyphen, a `W`, and two digits for the week of the year.

> 2017-W01

Get clear on **your definition of a “week”**. The ISO 8601 definition is that:

- The Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the year, and
- Runs Monday-Sunday.

So years run either 52 or 53 weeks long. And note that under this definition, the first few days of the year may be in the prior year when week-numbering. Likewise, the last few days of the year may be in the following year when week-numbering.

If you want to indicate a particular day within that week, append a hyphen and a single digit running 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

Tip: To see ISO 8601 week numbers by default on your computer, you may need to adjust your OS setting. For example, on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_operating_systems#Mac_OS_X.2FOS_X.2FmacOS) set System Preferences > Language & Region > Calendar > ISO 8601 to make apps such as [*Calendar.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(Apple)) to display week numbers with this standard definition.

> 2017-W01-7

By the way, a couple of similar representations:

- An ordinal date meaning the year and the day-of-year-number running from 1-366 is year, a hyphen, and a three-digit number: `2017-123`
- Month-Day without year is two hyphens, month number, hyphen, and day-of-month number: `--01-07`

Note that the use of `Locale` as seen in the Question is irrelevant here with the standard ISO 8601 formats.

## `YearWeek`

> Unfortunatley there is no object like YearMonth for weeks...

Ahhh, but there *is* such a class.

For a class to directly represent the idea of a week-year, see the [correct Answer by Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41494575/642706). That Answer shows the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library’s class [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html).

The [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class can directly parse and generate strings in standard format.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2017-W01" );
```

You can compare the `YearWeek` objects with methods: `compareTo`, `equals`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`.

```
yw.isBefore( thatYw )
```

The ThreeTen-Extra project offers other classes such as [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) that you may find useful.